# What are the disadvantages of using an adder instead of a clamper?

Tags: offset, clamp

I must use an offset an AC signal to measure through ADC. The traditional way or most of the resources point me to use the following clamper circuit:

[image: Clamper circuit]

However, I also see that the following adder circuit will give the same result:

[image: Adder circuit to generate offset]

Apart from using two op-amps, is there any other disadvantage in the adder circuit?

Comment: The output of your 2nd circuit is zero

Comment: Is 'R' really connected how it is represented in the first circuit?

Comment: @devnull, Yes, i saw it from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linear_integrated_circuits_applications/linear_integrated_circuits_applications_clampers.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

- An adder will let the A/D converter measure the entire range of the input voltage, AC and DC
- What you call a "clamp" (it's actually AC coupling) will let the A/D converter measure the entire peak-to-peak range of the input voltage, regardless of its DC offset

Having said that, your adder circuit is more complex than needed.

All you need is 2 resistors. No op-amp needed (unless you also need amplification).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXU0T8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Note that the op-amp-less circuit can have some other problems in unusual situations; the 5V supply can backfeed current into the signal source, even when the signal is positive; some signal sources may not like this. Or if the signal source goes above 5V, it can feed current into the 5V supply, which also may not like that. In most situations it's fine, but do be aware of the limitations!

Comment: @Hearth. Your point is that, if the source is not low impedance, then there should be a high-impedance buffer betweenit and the measuring device. True. But that's true regardless of whether one is using either of OP's suggested circuits or my suggested circuit: in all 3 cases, a current of < 1 mA is injected into the source.